# Is there a way to make a setable function in a user defined object

Tags: vb.net

Is there a way to set an object method like a property? 
I want to be able to just call the function like `myObj.myFunc()` but I want to set where myFunc will point when i instantiate myObj. As of right now i have it as a public event that i can add a handler to at init but it does seem like the best option.

Comment: Create a property of type [**`Action`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.110).aspx) in your class and set it to whatever you want. Then call `yourAction.Invoke()` when you want to execute the function.

Comment: Ohh Action, that works much better then what i was playing with!! was looking into 'Public Property myFunc As Func(Of string)' then invoking that.... thank you!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @VisualVincent said:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim myObj As New myObj(Sub() Console.WriteLine("1"))
        ' OR
        Dim myObj2 As New myObj(AddressOf myFunc)

        myObj2.myFunc.Invoke

    End Sub

    Sub myFunc()
        Console.WriteLine("2")
    End Sub

End Module

Class myObj

    Public Sub New(myFunc As Action)
        Me.myFunc = myFunc
    End Sub

    Property myFunc As Action

End Class
```